# Create new bootstrap classes with breakpoints

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a bunch of new classes using the bootstrap 4 breakpoints and I am wanting to use sass to generate them, but I am a little unsure exactly how to do this.

Basically the classes would be like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .bg-md-img {
        background-image: none !important;
    }
}
```

But obviously for each breakpoint. I know there is the `media-breakpoint-down` mixin I can use somehow, but I am not quite sure how to loop through the breakpoints properly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the background image? Is there a different image for each breakpoint? Are there other classes are you adding?

Comment: The section has a background image pulled in and set inline, which I want to hide mobile. I could do it easily by making some unique classes, but I am trying to move towards helper classes which can be reused elsewhere. Also, figuring this out should help me make other classes.

Comment: Ok, just trying to figure out why you want to "loop" instead of just setting it for 1 breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how the Bootstrap grid columns are made for each breakpoint in the `make-grid-columns` mixin in `grid_framework.scss`.

You would do something similar...

```
// loop through each breakpoint
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
    .bg#{$infix}-img {
      ..
    }
}


// css for one breakpoint
// change style on sm only
@include media-breakpoint-between(sm, md){
  .bg-sm-img {
      ...
  }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/Zjk1ybVJHZ

Comment: Tweaked it slightly, but it works thanks.
 `@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);
    @include media-breakpoint-down($breakpoint) {
        .bg#{$infix}-image {
            background-image: none !important;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going for a simpler approach which seems to work nicely:

```
@each $name, $value in $grid-breakpoints {
    @media all and (max-width: $value) {
        .bg-#{$name}-img {
            background-image: none !important;
        }
    }
}
```